# Implementation of Adversarial Loss In Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement an adversarial loss in keras. 
The model consists of two networks, one auto-encoder (the target model) and one discriminator. The two models share the encoder.

I created the adversarial loss of the auto-encoder by setting a keras variable

```
def get_adv_loss(d_loss):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return some_loss(y_true, y_pred) - d_loss
    return loss

discriminator_loss = K.variable()
L = get_adv_loss(discriminator_loss)
autoencoder.compile(..., loss=L)
```

and during training I interleave `train_on_batch` of `discriminator` and `autoencoder` to update `discriminator_loss`

```
d_loss = disciminator.train_on_batch(x, y_domain)
discriminator_loss.assign(d_loss)
a_loss, ... = self.segmenter.train_on_batch(x, y_target)
```

However, I found out that the value of these variables is frozen when the model is compiled. I tried to recompile the model during training but that raise the error

> Node 'IsVariableInitialized_13644': Unknown input node
>   'training_12/Adam/Variable'

which I guess it means i cant recompile during training? any suggestion on how i can inject the discriminator loss in the autoencoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras model supports multiple outputs. So just include your discirminator into your keras model and [freeze](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-freeze-keras-layers) the discrminator layers, if the discriminator should not be trained.

The next question would be how to combine autoencoder loss and discriminator loss. Luckily keras [model.compile](https://keras.io/models/model/) supports loss weights. If autoencoder is your first output and discriminator is your second you could do something like `loss_weights=[1, -1]`. So a better discriminator is worse for the autoencoder.

Edit: Here is an example, how to implement an Adversary Network:

```
# Build your architecture
auto_encoder_input = Input((5,))
auto_encoder_net = Dense(10)(auto_encoder_input)
auto_encoder_output = Dense(5)(auto_encoder_net)

discriminator_net = Dense(20)(auto_encoder_output)
discriminator_output = Dense(5)(discriminator_net)

# Define outputs of your model
train_autoencoder_model = Model(auto_encoder_input, [auto_encoder_output, discriminator_output])
train_discriminator_model = Model(auto_encoder_input, discriminator_output)

# Compile the models (compile the first model and then change the trainable attribute for the second)
for layer_index, layer in enumerate(train_autoencoder_model.layers):
    layer.trainable = layer_index < 3

train_autoencoder_model.compile('Adam', loss=['mse', 'mse'], loss_weights=[1, -1])        

for layer_index, layer in enumerate(train_discriminator_model.layers):
    layer.trainable = layer_index >= 3

train_discriminator_model.compile('Adam', loss='mse')

# A simple example how a training can look like
for i in range(10):
    auto_input = np.random.sample((10,5))
    discrimi_output = np.random.sample((10,5))
    train_discriminator_model.fit(auto_input, discrimi_output, steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=1)
    train_autoencoder_model.fit(auto_input, [auto_input, discrimi_output], steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=1)
```

As you can see there is no much magic behind building an Adversary Model with keras.

Comment: as far as I knew when you have multiple losses, each loss is applied to each output independently. Is it different from computing an actual adversarial loss that flows back into the auto-encoder? Cuz I want the auto-encoder to be affected by the loss of the discriminator, but not the discriminator to be affected by the autoencoder

Comment: In my opinion it's a much more elegant solution, which is easier to implement and more keras like. Also your discriminator gets the output from the autoencoder which is not freezed, so the autoencoder weights will be updated by the factor  of Loss_weights. I don't know if keras combine the losses first and then update the weights or just combine the updates from the weights. But the result should be the same.

Comment: Uh on that I totally agree, I thought about: it's much more elegant :-) But I have to make sure the discriminator does not receive the loss of the auto-encoder.

Comment: If you freeze the layers of the discriminator properly the discriminator ist not able to update the weights. In my past use cases I used two models, which were layer-wise exactly the same. But in one I freezed the discriminator and in the other iI freezed the autoencoder. With freezed layers the particular part is not able to learn anything. In case of training the discriminator the model does not need the output of the autoencoder, so you could just define the discriminator-output in this model.

Comment: Works! Compiling and recompiling takes quite some time though :-(

Comment: Why do you need to recompile? You have two different models for training (but with shared weights). And both have to be compiled only once. https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers Here is an example how to share layers in the same model, but you can also share them between models.

Comment: mmmm i see your point: i tried freeze discriminator, compile autoencoder, unfreeze discriminator, compile discriminator. At this point I think i should ignore the warning `UserWarning: Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights, did you set model.trainable without calling model.compile after ?
  'Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable`

Comment: I posted an updatet answer with an example code. With this code I don't get the warning you mentioned.

Comment: ah. which version of keras are you using? cuz I do.

Comment: I'm using keras version 2.2.2  with tensorflow backend 1.10.0. Also this is by far not a new feature. I used similiar code over a year ago. (Since then, I didn't train an adversary again though). The Warning is alarming because it indicates, something is wrong with freezing layers. You can double check by using `model.summary` which tells you the amount of trainable and not trainable parameters.

Comment: there i see the difference now: in my case the discriminator takes in input the latent space of the autoencoder, `auto_encoder_net` in your case. And if you do it like that, then you get the same error also on your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179016/discussion-between-dennis-ec-and-user1384636).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you decide to go deep in the keras source code, I don't think you can do this easily. Before writing your own adversarial module, you should check the existing works carefully. As far as I know, [keras-adversarial](https://github.com/bstriner/keras-adversarial/) is still used by many people. Of course, it only supports old keras versions, e.g. 2.0.8.

Several other things:

1. be careful when you freeze your model weights. If you first compile a model and then freeze some weights, these weights are still trainable, because when the train function is generated during compiling. So you should freeze weights first then compile.
2. `keras-adversarial` does this job in a more elegant way. Instead of making two models, shared weights but freeze some weights in different ways, it creates two train functions, one for each player.

Comment: Indeed recompiling the weights after every freeze / unfreeze takes quite some time. I came across keras-adversial but I thought it was no longer developed. But I will look at how they do it